# how to remove Xelement without its children node using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is my `XML`,

```
<A>
    <B  id="ABC">
      <C name="A" />
      <C name="B" />     
    </B>
    <X>
     <B id="ZYZ">
      <C name="A" />
      <C name="B" />
     </B>
    </X>
</A>
```

I'm using following code to remove **`<X>`** node without deleting its descents/childrens,

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\parsedXml.xml");
doc.Descendants("A").Descendants("X").Remove();
```

But is removing entire **`<X>`** block.

**Expected output :**

```
<A>
    <B  id="ABC">
      <C name="A" />
      <C name="B" />     
    </B>
     <B id="ZYZ">
      <C name="A" />
      <C name="B" />
     </B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = doc.Root.Element("X");
x.Remove();
doc.Root.Add(x.Elements());
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding to the previous parent element of `x`.

Comment: ... and also support for multiple `X` elements.

Answer (score 4):

Approved answer will always add children to the end of document. If you need to remove entry in the middle of the document and keep children where they sit, do following:

```
x.AddAfterSelf(x.Nodes());
x.Remove();
```

Following code removes all `<x>` nodes keeping children in the correct place:

```
while (doc.Descendants("x").Count() > 0)
{
    var x = doc.Descendants("x").First();
    x.AddAfterSelf(x.Nodes());
    x.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve Mike's useful answer slightly.

The reason you can't just iterate `Descendants` once is because `AddAfterSelf()` creates copies. After the first removal you're iterating children of the removed element rather than their replacements in the document.

However, if you iterate them **backwards**, then any copied children will have already been processed, so you can get away with a single pass:

```
foreach(var x in xdoc.Descendants("x").Reverse())
{
    x.AddAfterSelf(x.Nodes());
    x.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If node name is deprecated and must not be used in the whole document, just use ReplaceWith:

```
var xNode = doc.Descendants("x");
for (int i = 0; i < xNode.Count; i++)
{
    xNode[i].ReplaceWith(xNode[i].Nodes());
}
```