# Remove first named node without childs

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this xml file :

```
<a>
  <Directory name="dir1">
    <b>test1</b>
    <Directory name="dir2">
      <c>test2</c>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</a>
```

I will remove Directory with name "dir1" without childs.
I would like this :

```
<a>
    <b>test1</b>
    <Directory name="dir2">
      <c>test2</c>
    </Directory>
</a>
```

Exact XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="APP">
      <Directory Id="dirA4F7A43D3DBF467AC127F1422D00240E" Name="folder">
        <Component Id="cmpCCEB1A915DCA242C688E53A21CE3C3CD" Guid="">
          <File Id="fil0507E8B9603778F116316274B82F92D9" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Documents and Settings\folder\toto.xls" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="54" Guid="">
          <File Id="fil1E594FEBC557E93E0B15FC1DC3DE315F" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\Documents and Settings\folder\APP.CFG" />
        </Component>
        ......
        ...
      </Directory>
     </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I read others stackoverflow topic but it doesn't work or for a no named XElement.
I would use Linq-to-Xml.
I tried just this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21730252/4517421) for try to remove the first directory, but it doesn't work (x is null):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";
var x = doc.Root.Element(ns + "Directory");
x.Remove();
doc.Root.Add(x.Elements());
```

Do you have solution ?

Comment: Have you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14969753/4063639

Comment: The exact code you've shown with the XML you've shown works fine. Therefore there's some difference we can't see between your *real* XML and what you've shown us. (My guess is it's a namespace issue.)

Comment: I updated my code with namespace, i think that is a namespace issue but i don't find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are looking for is not a child of the root element, it is a descendant, so change

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";
var x = doc.Root.Element(ns + "Directory");
x.Remove();
doc.Root.Add(x.Elements());
```

to

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi";
XElement directory = doc.Descendants(ns + "Directory").First();
XElement parent = directory.Parent;
directory.Remove();
parent.Add(directory.Elements());
```

Or with attribute value :

```
XElement directory = doc.Descendants(ns + "Directory").First(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "value");
```